# jQuery datepicker return not ok date format

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I can't correct display my date. I in select date choose friday. Example: if I pick Monday 26.8 datepicker return (onselect) friday 30.8. Date format must be dd.mm.yy.

Here is code: http://jsfiddle.net/JBrvn/8/

```
$(function () {
    $('#to').attr('disabled', true);
    $("#from").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            var x = selectedDate.split('.');
            var d = new Date(x[1] + ',' + x[0] + ',' + x[2]);
            var res = d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7);
            var dateMsg = d.getDate() + '.' + (d.getMonth() + 1) + '.' + d.getFullYear();
            $("#to").removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker({
                minDate: dateMsg,
                dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
                onSelect: function (date) {
                     var d = new Date(date);
                     var index = d.getDay();
                     if (index == 0) {
                        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 5);
                    }
                    else if (index == 1) {
                        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 4);
                    }
                    else if (index == 2) {
                        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 3);
                    }
                    else if (index == 3) {
                        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 2);
                    }
                    else if (index == 4) {
                        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
                    }
                    else if (index == 5) {
                        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 0);
                    }
                    else if (index == 6) {
                        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 6);
                    }
                    var curr_day = d.getDate();
                    var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1;
                    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
                    $(this).val((curr_day<10? "0":"")+curr_day + "." +(curr_month<10? "0":"")+curr_month + "." + curr_year);
                     }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Date](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) object is javascript, not jQuery, so it doesn't obey the jQuery datepicker's date format.  In order to use the result of the first datepicker to create a date object to feed the second, you will need to convert it to a format that `Date` understands, possibly:

```
onSelect: function (dateString) {
   var date = dateString.split("."); //split the string into an array
   var d = new Date(date[2],date[1],date[0]); //feed the year, month, and date in the order Date expects
```

Comment: For the month use `date[1]-1`.